How to Reduce Excessive Celery Connections and Requests in a Dash App Using Upstash Redis
Following the first example on the Dash Background Callbacks tutorial, I'm using Upstash Redis for both the Celery broker and backend. While the system functions correctly, I'm encountering an issue where Celery is generating excessive connections and read requests to Redis. These requests persist at a high rate even when the system is idle.
I want to reduce the number of commands to control my Upstash billing, as I am currently being charged even when the app is idle. This can lead to many unnecessary commands and increased costs.
I'm running this setup on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS with Python version 3.10.12. The software versions I'm using are Celery 5.4.0, Dash 2.16.1, and Redis 5.0.3.
import time
import ssl
import os
import dotenv

dotenv.load_dotenv()

from dash import Dash, DiskcacheManager, CeleryManager, Input, Output, html, callback

deployed = True
if deployed:
    from celery import Celery

    ssl_options = {
        'ssl_cert_reqs': ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
    }

    host=os.getenv('REDIS_HOST')
    port=os.getenv('REDIS_PORT')
    password=os.getenv('REDIS_PASSWORD')
    connection_link = f"rediss://:{password}@{host}:{port}"

    celery_app = Celery(
        __name__, broker=connection_link, backend=connection_link,
        broker_use_ssl=ssl_options,
        redis_backend_use_ssl=ssl_options,
        broker_connection_retry_on_startup=True
    )

    background_callback_manager = CeleryManager(celery_app)
else:
    # Diskcache for non-production apps when developing locally
    import diskcache
    cache = diskcache.Cache("./cache")
    background_callback_manager = DiskcacheManager(cache)

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div([html.P(id="paragraph_id", children=["Button not clicked"])]),
        html.Button(id="button_id", children="Run Job!"),
    ]
)

@callback(
    output=Output("paragraph_id", "children"),
    inputs=Input("button_id", "n_clicks"),
    background=True,
    manager=background_callback_manager,
)
def update_clicks(n_clicks):
    time.sleep(2.0)
    return [f"Clicked {n_clicks} times"]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

Here are some metrics from the Upstash Redis dashboard that might help explain the app's behavior. To gather these logs, I executed celery -A app.celery_app worker --loglevel=DEBUG and let it run for a few minutes before terminating the process. During this time, I did not initiate any other actions, so no user-driven tasks were being processed. In fact, I did not even execute the command python app.py to start the app.
The images show that although no user actions were taken, 10 connections were established with Redis. Additionally, there were 5 misses per second compared to only 0.03 hits per second. Finally, approximately 2 commands were executed per second, most of which were read requests.



Here are the logs when celery -A app.celery_app worker --loglevel=DEBUG is executed:
[DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Preparing bootsteps.
[DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Building graph...
[DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: New boot order: {StateDB, Beat, Timer, Hub, Pool, Autoscaler, Consumer}
[DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Preparing bootsteps.
[DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Building graph...
[DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: New boot order: {Connection, Agent, Events, Heart, Mingle, Gossip, Tasks, Control, event loop}
 
 -------------- celery@xxxxxxxx v5.4.0 (opalescent)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-6.5.0-28-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35 2024-04-23 19:55:28
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         app:xxxxx
- ** ---------- .> transport:   rediss://:**xxxxxxxx
- ** ---------- .> results:     rediss://:**xxxxxxxx
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 8 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
                

[tasks]
  . celery.accumulate
  . celery.backend_cleanup
  . celery.chain
  . celery.chord
  . celery.chord_unlock
  . celery.chunks
  . celery.group
  . celery.map
  . celery.starmap
  . long_callback_5d75ecd8ae8d740c0c10d6487e05121f26eca9bd

[DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Hub
[DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Pool
[DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Consumer
[DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Connection
[INFO/MainProcess] Connected to rediss://:**xxxxxxxx
[DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Events
[DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Heart
[DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Mingle
[INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Gossip
[DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Tasks
[DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Control
[DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting event loop
[DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Hub.register Pool...
[INFO/MainProcess] celery@xxxxxxxx ready.
[DEBUG/MainProcess] basic.qos: prefetch_count->32

Attempts Made

Following a suggestion from SO, I added the recommended code, but there was no change in the number of connections or commands. I also tried implementing the code suggested by the question's author (celery_app.conf.redis_max_connections = 2), but it had no effect.

Based on this SO suggestion, I added celery_app.conf.broker_pool_limit = 0, which reduced the number of connections from 10 to 8. This is an improvement, but it's still higher than desired. The author of the answer mentioned something he called "Connections Math," stating that "the master Celery process needs 8 connections." However, it's unclear whether this is the minimum required number of connections or if further reductions are possible, especially since I'm observing 8 connections even when the app is idle.

Executing celery -A app.celery_app worker --loglevel=DEBUG --concurrency=2 (concurrency set to 2) while also using celery_app.conf.broker_pool_limit = 0 did not resolve the issue. In this scenario, the number of connections increased back to 10.

I've also looked into a related GitHub Issue, but it remains unanswered at the time of my writing. Additionally, a response on the dash forum suggests the same approach as in item 2, which hasn't resolved my issue.


UPDATE
I couldn't resolve the issue, but I switched my broker to sqs, which has improved the situation.
